# Cors Filter Not working Properly in Spring with session management

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, http

I added cors filter in the server side for rest api cross origin requests. After adding the filter ,my session management is not working in the application. It is creating a new session in every request so my application is not working. Can any one suggests how can I implement the cors filter with a session management in `spring`.

```
public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(CORSFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");



        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if(session.isNew()){
            LOG.info("New session is jutst created");

            session.setAttribute("SESSIONID", session.getId());

            LOG.info("new session id..."+session.getId());
        }else{
            LOG.info("This is old session");
        }



         String origin = request.getHeader("Origin");
            String method=request.getMethod();
            System.out.println("method id  " +method);

        if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            LOG.info("Sending Header....");
            // CORS "pre-flight" request
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Request Headers

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:57
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8081
Referer:http://localhost:8081/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Post a sample of the request header that your application sent? Am thinking some spring session headers aren't configured properly with CORS

Comment: Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:57
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8081
Referer:http://localhost:8081/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36

Comment: add `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to your configuration, seems like cookie information pertaining to the sessions are missing.

Comment: I added like this in CORS filter    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");    Still not working

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am having same issue. :-/

Comment: No , i did not got the solution  Mital Pritmani